# Oracle: Create Table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, ddl

I want to create table and I try did it as following:

[image]

And when I try execute this query I get an error

Comment: The error is pretty self-explanatory. A column constraint cannot reference the value of another column.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile 

devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the 

question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Answer (score 2):

There is a comma missing before "CONSTRAINT". So for Database it seems like you are creating constraint on a column "waktu_selesai" (the last one) whereas you need to create a table-level constraint in order to make this thing work.

```
create table jadwal(
  id_jadwal number generated always as identity primary key,
  hari varchar2(10),
  waktu_mulai varchar2(5) not null,
  waktu_selesai varchar2(5) not null,
  constraint jadwal_check_waktu check (to_number(substr(waktu_mulai, 1, 2)) >         to_number(substr(waktu_selesai, 1, 2)))
);
```